# Uniqueness of abelian group structure on a given set and recursive algorithms

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, recursive-algorithms

If we have some function $f$ under $\mathbb{Z}$ and
$$f(a, f(b, c)) = f(f(a, b), c)$$
$$f(a, b) = f(b, a)$$
$$f(a, 0) = a$$
$$f(a, -a) = 0$$
meaning $f$ is an abelian group with an identity element of $0$. Is that enough to prove that $f$ is addition? In other words, is an abelian group with a specific identity element unique within a certain domain? Similarly, could multiplication be proved if we had an abelian group with an identity element of $1$?

More generally, I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to deduce an algorithm (set of simple unambiguous recursive rules) from a set of axioms for some operation under a domain (axioms could perhaps be thought of as a form of ambiguous recursion). The first step is to figure out if a set of axioms can define the uniqueness of an operation. The more difficult step is to actually infer the specific recursive steps necessary.

Comment: NB you must also insist of the existence of an inverse map in order to guarantee that $f$ defines a group structure; the above axioms guarantee only that it defines a monoid: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this would imply that all (infinite) countable groups are isomorphic (as the underlying sets of any two such groups are in bijection), but that is not the case: For example both $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}, +)$ are countable, but they are not isomorphic, because the former is generated by a single element but the latter is not.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying, but why exactly does what I describe imply all countable groups? I was just trying to prove the nature of addition under a single countable group. I understand that the nature of abelian group alone can't be inferred (as you described), but if we restrict the focus to a single countable group, is the situation any different?

Comment: For any (infinite) countable group $(G, \ast)$, one can pick any bijection $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to G$ that maps $0$ to the identity and define the operation $\star$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ by $a \star b := \phi^{-1}(\phi(a) \ast \phi(b))$, and this construction guarantees that $(\mathbb{Z}, \star)$ is isomorphic to $(G, \ast)$ via $\phi$. In particular, if $(G, \ast)$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$, $\star$ defines a group structure on $\mathbb{Z}$ not isomorphic to $+$.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by "restrict the focus to a single countable group", but if one means that one has a set, e.g., $\mathbb{Z}$ with prescribed identity element and an isomorphism type of a group with the appropriate cardinality, asking whether there is a unique operation that makes that set a group of the appropriate isomorphism type and with the given identity, the answer is no (at least as long as the group has $> 2$ elements). For example, in the previous comment take $(G, \ast) = (\mathbb{Z}, +)$ and $\phi$ to be any nonidentity bijection such that $\phi(0) = 0$.